# Remove the first 3 levels from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've trying to remove the first 3 levels from my multidimensional array, is there a 'cleaner' way to perform the below code?

```
$array = array_shift(array_shift(array_shift($this->fullArray())));
```

This is the array

```
 array(1) { 
    ["GetAllJobByLanguageResult"]=> array(1) { 
      ["Results"]=> array(1) { 
        ["AvJobSearch"]=> array(2) { 
           [0]=> array(21) { 
             ["Id"]=> int(103689) 
             ["Title"]=> string(13) "Test Vacature" 
             ["PublishDate"]=> string(23) "2018-06-08T14:11:05.237"
```

Comment: show your array

Comment: also, show desired output

Comment: So my array starts like this, and I want to remove the GetAllJobByLanguageResult, Results and AvJobSearch keys:
array(1) {
  ["GetAllJobByLanguageResult"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Results"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["AvJobSearch"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(21) {
          ["Id"]=>
          int(103689)
          ["Title"]=>
          string(13) "Test Vacature"
          ["PublishDate"]=>
          string(23) "2018-06-08T14:11:05.237"
          ["EndDate"]=>

Comment: Are you referring to first 3 levels or first 3 values of an array ? because levels and values have both different meanings.

Comment: @KishenNagaraju I mean levels

Comment: The above code indicates that you want to remove first 3 values.

Comment: @Tom edit your question and add the array there. Nobody can read it in comments.

Comment: @Andreas I have added it now

Comment: @Tom and you only want to keep what is inside [0]? Then my answer should work for you.

Comment: @Tom did my answer solve the problem or do I need to edit it?

Comment: @Andreas sorry I was working on something else, yes your second solution with the exact path worked exactly as needed, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop the number of levels you want to remove.

I use array_keys to find the keys and overwrite $arr with $arr one level deeper.
This is then repeated the number of times specified in the for loop.

```
$arr = [["second" => ["something" => ["else" => [1,2,3]]]]];

For($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
    $keys = array_keys($arr);
    $arr = $arr[$keys[0]];
}

Var_dump($arr);
```

https://3v4l.org/WiOrI

If you know the exact path then you can skip the loop and just write:

```
$arr = $arr[0]["second"]["something"];
```

But the loop is useful if you are not sure what the keys are.

Answer (score 0):

you are using a static way to remove elements of array and `array_shift` is not for remove elements

Try by this

```
<?php

$a = array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue");


$i=1;
foreach($a as $key=>$value){
    if($i < 3){
        unset($a[$key]);
    }
    $i++;
}

print_r($a);
```